# =COUNTIF giving FALSE even though there should be a match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following code:

```
=IF(Calculations!$B$1=Q1,
IF($B$3="All",
COUNTIFS('TAS'!$A$3:$A$999,"="&Calculations!$B$1,
'TAS'!$E$2:$E$999, Calculations!$F$8,
'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10),
COUNTIFS('TAS'!$A$3:$A$999,"="&Calculations!$B$1,
'TAS'!$E$2:$E$999, Calculations!$F$8,
'TAS'!$H$3:$H$999,Calculations!$B$4,
'TAS'!$D$2:$D$999, Calculations!$C10)))
```

$B$1 is a cell that draws the values from a dropdown menu in another sheet `=Dashboard!$D$2`

However, even when I have the dropdown for $B$1 set to "Q1", the first formula gives me `FALSE` - I double checked that there are no extra spaces or characters anywhere. When $B$1 equals Q1, why is the above formula false?

Comment: Note that the ranges need to be all the same size... some of them start in row 2 and some start in row 3. `$A$3:$A$999`, but `$E$2:$E$999` and so on.

Comment: `=Q1` is quite different from `="Q1"`.